# How to hide the article at the home page in joomla 2.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, joomla2.5

How to hide the article at the home page in joomla 2.5?

Some times you want to have your home page with out showing an empty article.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to do this, and they all depend on your specific use case.

For example, if you want to hide it only on the homepage, you can change your template to the following.

Find:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Change it to:

```
$menu = & JSite::getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() != $menu->getDefault()) {
    <jdoc:include type="component" />;
}
```

No need to worry about JS.

Comment: Don't use `&` for objects. That's PHP4.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a problem if you dont have any specific background in your template.

Otherwise you can use jquery to hide the div that contains the main body.

You can add the folowing java script to your template index.php before the  tag

In this sample i also want to make active the page forum thats why i am using a switch insted of if.

```
    <script>
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();

    var currentPage = <?php echo("'".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."'"); ?>;

    switch (currentPage) {
        case '/':
             j('#rt-mainbody').hide();
            break;
        case '/forum':
            j(".item213").addClass("active");
            break;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: not a good solution as some people might have JS turned off. Should go for a PHP method

Comment: About js turned off it is out of reality only 1% of the market has js disable (http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/many-users-javascript-disabled-14121.html) but of course will be better if you have a solution with php if you are working with kunena, jevents jomsocial and jreviews in one site you will see that it is a bit triki

Answer (score 0):

Would be best to use a PHP method rather than jQuery. You can add this code to your index.php in the template folder.

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
        $doc = JFactoty::getDocument(); //remove if already defined
        $doc->addStyleDeclaration(" #element { display:none; } ");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just make the  statement conditional to not being on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that Lodder.
Copied you code and at first it didn't work... then I saw why

```
 $doc = JFactoty::getDocument();
```

**JFACTOTY** had a typo

when I changed it, worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this as simple as changing the menu item type from frontpage to something else?  for example, change the menu module type to featured articles and then have no featured articles works for sure (it's how i accomplish this).  then if i want an article on there, i just 'feature' it and voila...